How to yank only to specified register and do not touch (change) default " register?
I have mapping for duplicating current line in insert mode:
inoremap <C-d> <Esc>`^mzYp`zi<Down>

I want to set up it in a way it does not change default " register by specifying some special register like a or 9:
inoremap <C-d> <Esc>`^mz"aY"ap`zi<Down>
inoremap <C-d> <Esc>`^mz"9Y"9p`zi<Down>

But yanking to this specific registers also affects default " register.
How to yank to some register without touching default register? Copying to what registers will not affect default register? Or how to make key mapping that will not affect default register?

This is much simpler and does not modify registers or bookmarks.
inoremap <c-d> <esc>:t.<cr>gi


Copying to what registers will not affect default register?

Default register is a pointer, not a real register. So no contents will get modified but the "pointer" will, as you're copying/deleting into any other register. So in mappings and scripts it's often better to use only commands and leave user's context intact.

This one is working the same as my inoremap <C-d> <Esc>^mzYpzi<Down>. It also saves cursor position. And even in border cases (start and end of line). Thanks!

Is it possible to configure it for normal mode also with preserving cursor position? nnoremap <silent> <c-d> :t.<cr> performs line duplication, but resets position to the start of line.

@AntonSamokat You can set a mark but, imo, it doesn't worth. Just get used to the fact the cursor in normal mode can jump to the start of line on numerous occasions.

Am I understand correctly that default register is a pointer to any of the last modified specific register?

@AntonSamokat Yes, you can browse through C source code to find exact conditions it gets changed.
